# Display another cell of table except the selected cell html(table.cell(this).data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to get from a table the selected cell + another cell.
This is my table:

```
  <table id="display1">
  <thead>
          <th>Teams</th>
          <th>Odd1</th>
          <th>Odd2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Team1-Team2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Team3-Team4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 <div id="selectedOption"></div>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
  var table = $('table.display1').DataTable()
$('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $("#selectedOption").html(table.row(this).data()[2]);
        $('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        $("#selectedOption1").html(table.cell(this).data());
        });
    });
```

When i click Odd1 or Odd2 ,i want to display in div:

```
 Team1-Team2 1 
 Team1-Team2 2
 Team3-Team4 5
```

What is wrong with my code

Comment: what is happening right now ?

Comment: Why are you creating a delegate binding inside a delegate binding?

Comment: I get only the selected cell: for example only " 1" or "Team1-Team2"

Comment: you not defined **table** in the javacript

Comment: i used the id of the table

Comment: Please post your entire code.  Otherwise if we can't see where things are coming from, we're going to keep asking about those things rather than potentially getting to your actual problem.

Comment: i also have,in the beginning of my script this line : var table = $('table.display1').DataTable

Comment: I already updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at your $(this) and also table is not defined...

Is this near to what you want..

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
       var table = $("#display1");console.log(this)
        $("#selectedOption").html($(this));
        $('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        $("#selectedOption1").html($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



  <table id="display1">
  <thead>
          <th>Teams</th>
          <th>Odd1</th>
          <th>Odd2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Team1-Team2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Team3-Team4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 <div id="selectedOption"></div>
```

Comment: This is still doing a delegate binding inside a delegate binding which will create the inner binding multiple times.

Comment: How can i fix it?How to get both results in one binding?